# Rulings in islam regarding women leadership

Tags: women

I would like to know if its haram in islam for a women to be a president or a vice president of a country. 
Please let me know why if its haram.
Thank you

Comment: Simple, can a Muslim women meet everyone openly (non-mahram). A leader have to have the ability to lead the people personally.

Answer (score 1):

I came across two similar Hadiths on this:

> Narrated Abu Bakr:
>
> During the battle of Al-Jamal, Allah benefited me with a Word (I heard
>   from the Prophet). When the Prophet heard the news that the people of
>   the Persia had made the daughter of Khosrau their Queen (ruler), he
>   said, "Never will succeed such a nation as makes a woman their ruler."
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari 7099,  Vol. 9, Book 88, Hadith 219](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/92/50)

and

> Abu Bakrah said:
>
> "Allah restrained me with something that I heard from the Messenger of
>   Allah(s.a.w). When Kisra was destroyed, he said: 'Who did they have to
>   succeed him?' They said: 'His daughter.' So the Prophet(s.a.w) said:
>   'A people will never succeed who give their leadership to a woman.'"
>   He said: "So when 'Aishah arrived - meaning in Al-Basrah - I
>   remembered the saying of Messenger of Allah (ﷺ), so Allah restrained
>   me by it." Abu Eisa said: This Hadith is [Hasan] Sahih.
>
> [Jami` at-Tirmidhi 2262, Book 33, Hadith 105](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/105)

The hadiths do not explicitly say that it is Haram but there is a strong warning from the Prophet (SAW) to the people who choose a female leader over themselves.

But as a full discloser, I have come across some ulema who say it allowed for both men and women to lead their nations quoting Queen Sheba from Yemen at the time of Prophet Solomon (AS). Others have stated our shariah is different from the time of Prophet Solomon (AS).

We should not go far as stating as something is Haram when there is no explicit reference in the Islamic scriptures and no consensus among the ulema. At the same time, we should be mindful of the warning in the Hadith.

**Edit**:
Some have pointed out that the role of a ruler in the 21st century is very different from that of one back in the 7th century. Rulers in the past lead people in congregational prayers, delivered Friday sermons and led armies in the battle field which traditionally have been male dominated bastions. Todays leaders tend to be secular with no religious duties imposed on them.

I have my reservations with this argument as the daughter of Khosrau  neither had to lead congregational prayers nor deliver Friday sermons. Even in the battle field, she had a army chief to look after the affairs. Yet the Prophet warned his people.

In conclusion, I don't have a concrete answer but I pray to Allah that He shows us all the right way and help us choose humble, righteous,non-dictatorial leaders for our nations. Ameen

Answer (score -1):

Nop, it is a matter of right, the limit, There can never be a right, if one is not able to earn it, Yes, she can if, she is able to do the job according to the requirement of the job, A woman is unable to fulfill the demands of the job as a head of the state, so she can not be the head of the state by the Islamic law. Because there are no authority with out the accountability, nor any duties without the authority.